# Filter item duplicates clientside with C# HashSet

Tags: c#, client, hashset

Currently I have the problem, that I need to filter the result of an SQL query on the client. The amount of data which can be returned is between `5` and `50.000.000`. For every item there are between `1` and `5` duplicates.

My first idea was, to store every primary key of an item in a `HashSet<string>` and proof, whether it already exists or not. If a sql statement as more than one primary key, I would concat them with an underscore or something similar.

But i'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to do this. Is There some thing better than storing every primary key in a `HashSet<string>`?

P.S.: Modifying the sql query is sadly no option.

**EDIT**

Here is an example application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int items = 5000000;
        int fromDuplicates = 1;
        int toDuplicates = 5;

        Console.WriteLine("HashSet performance test");
        Console.WriteLine("Items: {0}", items);
        Console.WriteLine("Amount of duplicates between {0} - {1}", fromDuplicates, toDuplicates);

        IList<Guid> guids = new List<Guid>();
        Random rnd = new Random((Guid.NewGuid()).GetHashCode());
        for (int i = 0; i < items; i++)
        {
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid();

            // Create duplicates
            for (int y = 0; y < rnd.Next(fromDuplicates, toDuplicates); y++)
            {
                guids.Add(guid);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Begin test. Amount of items: {0}", guids.Count);

        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        HashSet<string> pkHashSet = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var g in guids)
        {
            var str = g.ToString();

            // Filter duplicates
            if (!pkHashSet.Contains(str))
            {
                pkHashSet.Add(str);
            }
        }

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed milliseconds: {0}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("Final item amount: " + pkHashSet.Count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

With this results. Seems to be pretty fast:

[image: HashSet]

> Hardware: i7-5600U (2,6GHz) / 8GB Ram Windows 10

Comment: What does your initial Query look like.. perhaps all you need to do is create a query that will pull back on Distinct records.. also why don't you clean up the duplicates or is there a reason to you're keeping the duplicates..? can you create your own stored procedure that pulls in the data to a temp table and from there create a query that strips an or filters out the duplicates.. can you show us something so we can understand what you're up against

Comment: We can not clean up the dublicates and `grouping` the data is even slower. Using `distinct` is absolutly the slowest version. Using a `HashSet<string>` is in this case much faster. And because we are query some extern system, we can not change any thing. So sadly, client filtering is the only option.

Comment: can you show what you have thus far using `HashSet<string>` how are you storing the data client side prior to doing filtering .. ? are you storing in a `DataTable` initially

Comment: Yes we are using `DataTable`. We have written our own DB cursor for retrieving data from a database. Currently i've only made a few tests with the `HashSet<string>`. I just add a value from a `DataRow['pk']` and than use the `Contains` method of the `HashSet`. If `Contains` returns false, i add the `DataRow` to the list of loaded data.

Comment: I'd have to see what you are doing to visualize code wise .. and Contains is good but can't you do filter on DataTable using the `Select function` and  `LIKE`

Comment: create a `filterDataTable` and do something like this 
`filterDataTable = someDataTable.Select("some field LIKE  '" & someValue & "%'")`

Comment: But when using `Select` with a `LIKE`, i need to know what to filter, or? But i only know the values after adding them to some list or some thing similiar. Ive added some test-code with the results. Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: Calling `new Random((Guid.NewGuid()).GetHashCode());` is a waste of time when `new Random();` works just as well (at least as you've used it in your code.)

Comment: Yes, but i wanted some seed, to be sure the generated values does not repeat when starting the application.